# ClearFocus returns true and triggers onFocusChange

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-view, android-alertdialog, android-2.3-gingerbread

This issue occurs only in versions below ICS. I have two EditTexts (username and password). Initially both the focus is false. On click of either I first call an AlertDialog. Onclick of negative button I clearfocus of both the EditTexts. When I clear the focus of the second (password) textField, the first one automatically resets to true.

```
 private void disclaimerDialog() {
        dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        dlgAlert.setTitle(R.string.testApp);
        dlgAlert.setCancelable(false);

        dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("Accept", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                mDisclaimerAccepted = true;
            }
        });

        dlgAlert.setNegativeButton("Decline", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                hideKeyboard();
                userNameEditText.clearFocus();
                passwordEditText.clearFocus();

            }
        });

        dlgAlert.show();
    }



userNameEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!mDisclaimerAccepted && hasFocus) {
                    if (tempFileData != null) {
                        disclaimerDialog((EditText) view);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You haven't accepted the disclaimer. Please check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } 
            }
        });
passwordEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!mDisclaimerAccepted && hasFocus) {
                    if (tempFileData != null) {
                        disclaimerDialog((EditText) view);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You haven't accepted the disclaimer. Please check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } 
            }
        });
```

when I call passwordEditText.ClearFocus() it return true on onFocusChange for userNameEditText. but not vice versa.

I have tried every blog and all questions on stackoverflow. This is a problem only in Gingerbread.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue.
I have also added an onFocusChange listener. So basically the touch listener works till the alert dialog is accepted(if you decline the alert dialog, the touch listener will still be enabled.). On accept I disable the touch listener by returning false and the focus change listener gets enabled.